# How to filter on an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm new in Javascript,
I want to Create a function that takes an array of non-negative integers and strings and return a new array without the strings.

Examples
`filterArray([1, 2, "aasf", "1", "123", 123])` ➞ `[1, 2, 123]`

I've tried this code :

```js
function filterArray(arr) {
    var j=0;
    var numArr;
    for (let i=0;i<length.arr;i++)
    {
        if (typeof arr[i] ==="number") 
        {
            numArr[j]=arr[i];
            j++;
        }       
    }
    return numArr
}
console.log(filterArray([1, 2, "aasf", "1", "123", 123]));
```

but i didn't arrive to run my code, can someone helps me ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: use `Array.prototype.filter`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** First the loop should be run up to `arr.length` not `length.arr`.

**2)** No need to use another counter variable `j`, you can use simply array as

```
var numArr = [];
```

and you can use `push` method to add elements in the array at the end.

```js
function filterArray(arr) {
  var numArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (typeof arr[i] === "number") {
      numArr.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return numArr;
}

console.log(filterArray([1, 2, "aasf", "1", "123", 123]))
// ➞ [1, 2, 123]
```

**Other alternatives**

```js
function filterArray(arr) {
  // return arr.filter((el) => +el === el);
  // or
  // return arr.filter((el) => typeof el !== `string`);
  // or
  return arr.filter(el => typeof el === "number");
}

console.log(filterArray([1, 2, "aasf", "1", "123", 123]));
```

Answer (score 2):

using the filter method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

```js
function filterArray(arr) {
    return arr.filter(x => typeof x === "number");
}

console.log(filterArray([1, 2, "aasf", "1", "123", 123]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.filter()` to filter your elements based on a condition given.

```js
function filterArray(arr) {
    return arr.filter(el => typeof el === 'number');
}
console.log(filterArray([1, 2, "aasf", "1", "123", 123]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just like this:

```js
const data = [1, 2, "aasf", "1", "123", 123];
const filtered = data.filter((d) => typeof d === "number");
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving the most optimized answer, I will try to address  a few problems with your code. You can look at any other answer to use the best code:

1. `length.arr` should be `arr.length`. That is how JS works.
2. `var numArr`, if you will access `numArr[0]` this will give you an error. Initialize with an empty array.

```
function filterArray(arr) {
    var j=0;
    var numArr = [];
    for (let i=0;i<arr.length;i++) 
        { 
        if (typeof arr[i] ==="number") 
        {numArr[j]=arr[i];
        j++;
        }       
        }
    return numArr
}
```

Make these changes and your code works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var arr = [1, 2, "aasf", "1", "123", 123],
    num = arr.filter(item => typeof item === "number")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this.

```
const arr = [1, 2, "aasf", "1", "123", 123]
const filteredData = arr.filter((item) =>  Number(item) === item );
```